# Issue with counter-increment in css

Tags: html, css

I am facing a problem with css counter-increment, number is not appearing in Output.Please help me.
Please explain me clearly.

This is my codepen: [codepen](http://codepen.io/venumadhavdiv/pen/ZOypJz?editors=1100)`enter code here`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"counter(number)"` will be detected as string. Just remove the `""`.

```
h1:before {
  counter-increment: number;
  content: counter(number);
}
```

If you want with period after number:

```
h1:before {
  counter-increment: number;
  content: counter(number) ". ";
}
```

Comment: thank you its working @currarpickt am getting number but am not getting "." after number.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the quotes around `counter(number)`.